# How to divide a buffer using geometry generator in QGIS 3.X

Tags: qgis, symbology, geometry-generator

Some background and working PostGIS query and Python script available here.

[How to split circles in 12 sections in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241393/how-to-split-circles-in-12-sections-in-postgis#)

I don't want to create a new polygon layer out of points. I really like QGIS Geometry generator. My idea is to use QGIS Geometry generator and show this divide buffer as symbol.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Prepare center points (used as seeds).

- Create your first center point as a point vector layer.
- Duplicate the point so that you have 12 points (in my Windows OS I will hit Ctrl+C to copy the point then hit Ctrl+V eleven (11) times.
- Then create a field to represent the center azimuth of each wedge (e.g. `"fid" * 30 - 15` in this example).

[image]

2) Start Geometry generator and give: `wedge_buffer($geometry, "az", 30, 50)`

[image]

Sorry#1: I had used `Geometry by Expression` but you can use `Geometry generator`.

Sorry#2: The figure shows center azimuth (15, 45, ...345) of each wedge buffer but you would be able to modify it easily.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was looking

Answer (score 6):

Great answer by [@Kazuhito](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84455/kazuhito)! An alternative could be to create a buffer on your point layer and then add another geometry generator layer to draw lines to represent the segments The value of `0.1` used in the expressions is the buffer distance, change this for your requirement.

1. Create the buffer using expression:

   ```
   buffer($geometry, 0.1, 36)
   ```

   [image: Create buffer]
2. Create the lines using expression:

   ```
   make_line( 
   make_point( $X + 0.1*cos(radians(0)), $Y + 0.1*sin(radians(0))),
   $geometry,
   make_point( $X + 0.1*cos(radians(30)), $Y + 0.1*sin(radians(30))),
   $geometry,
   make_point( $X + 0.1*cos(radians(60)), $Y + 0.1*sin(radians(60))),
   $geometry,
   make_point( $X + 0.1*cos(radians(90)), $Y + 0.1*sin(radians(90))),
   $geometry,
   make_point( $X + 0.1*cos(radians(120)), $Y + 0.1*sin(radians(120))),
   $geometry,
   make_point( $X + 0.1*cos(radians(150)), $Y + 0.1*sin(radians(150))),
   $geometry,
   make_point( $X + 0.1*cos(radians(180)), $Y + 0.1*sin(radians(180))),
   $geometry,
   make_point( $X + 0.1*cos(radians(210)), $Y + 0.1*sin(radians(210))),
   $geometry,
   make_point( $X + 0.1*cos(radians(240)), $Y + 0.1*sin(radians(240))),
   $geometry,
   make_point( $X + 0.1*cos(radians(270)), $Y + 0.1*sin(radians(270))),
   $geometry,
   make_point( $X + 0.1*cos(radians(300)), $Y + 0.1*sin(radians(300))),
   $geometry,
   make_point( $X + 0.1*cos(radians(330)), $Y + 0.1*sin(radians(330)))
   )
   ```

   [image: Make lines for segments]
3. Result:

   [image]